# Are there any web standards for voice over IP?

Tags: html, voip, web-standards

Web browser plug-ins such as Flash already provide VoIP functionality in a web browser, but is it possible to have browser VoIP without any plug-ins?

Ericsson Labs has posted information using the [device element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#devices) to allow for microphone input. This, in addition with WebSockets could be used to implement VoIP. However, the device element is not implemented in any web browser yet.

Comment: Short answer: like you said, not ready yet.

Comment: Mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't but the device element will likely be the way in the future, as you mentioned. I don't think it will take too long for browsers to look into it however. There are also the [WAC APIs](http://labs.opera.com/news/2010/12/22/), but they are only on mobile, and not shipping quite yet.

Update: There is now a standard in development called [WebRTC](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html). Drafts of this spec are supported by Chrome and Firefox. Microsoft have made an alternative proposal called [CU-RTC-Web](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/cu-rtc-web/cu-rtc-web.htm)