# Web based Voice over IP application with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, sockets, voip

I was planning to develop a project including VoIP functionality between mobile app client and web browser with Rails as back-end. After I did some research, I had several questions.

First I Google it around and found most of VoIP applications have a client installed. Is that possible to just use web browser to make a audio call? I did a project of simple computer-to-computer VoIP with Sockets and some Audio library. I think what I can do is to use sockets to connect web browser (JavaScript?) with mobile client. (I'm not very experienced with Client-side JavaScript so not sure what can be done in browser.)

Second I searched about real time application with Rails, and many other developers are talking about rails + node.js + socket.io + redis. For what I'm understanding (not know node.js very well), node.js is a server javascript engine. So does that means there are two back-end running for one application?

Last I searched about VoIP in rails and found Adhearsion for Ruby which is built on to asterisk. Adhearsion did have some way to integrate with rails which is good. But does this make for communicate with actual phone (i.e. regular phone call with phone number)? If I installed Adhearsion, do I answer the phone call through terminal or some client application or web browser?

I'll continue research more about Adhearsion and other stuff.

Any clarification or guidance would be very helpful. Thanks.

UPDATE:

As for first question, I found WebRTC probably the solution.

Some Sources:

[Are there any web standards for voice over IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628372/are-there-any-web-standards-for-voice-over-ip)

[SIP, asterisk, adhearson and VoIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492758/sip-asterisk-adhearson-and-voip)

[node.js + socket.io + redis + rails — RealTime application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915661/node-js-socket-io-redis-rails-realtime-application)
http://www.slideshare.net/DieterPisarewski/ruby-voip

Answer (score 2):

We use Twilio for SMS stuff.  I haven't used their voice features, but I think they may do what you want.  No affiliation and no idea if they really do, but might check them out.

https://www.twilio.com/voice

https://www.twilio.com/webrtc

https://www.twilio.com/client/mobile

Comment: I've been using Twilio for years -- absolutely love it.